# Stream to RTMP with Electron?

Tags: node.js, electron, rtmp

I have an RTMP server up and running and now I'd like to stream to it with an Electron app.
I could not find much info online regarding how to do this.
Any pointers?

Comment: Do you want to show a live stream on your electron app?

Comment: No, I want to broadcast a webcam/camera using Electron to a specified RTMP server.

Comment: Did you try FFmpeg?

Comment: FFMpeg is for video encoding. Not what I want.

Comment: @JaeLee ffmpeg can do it.